# My jetbrain has this issue showing :Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. Exception: Process 408 is still running

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to open application the error is happening

Then that is  solved i mention how i solved i attach the link also here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory

go through proper method

.lock file want to removed

Home directory

in macbook you can check both option os has also include

I restart my system then still the error happen .

I fix through the  link, jet brains have error solution

I restart my system then still the error happen .

- Home(user) mackintosh > Library
- Library will hide from this section : how to open in mac: command + shift + .(dot)
- JetBrains
- Pycharm version (2023.2.0)
- .lock option (you want to delete)

it will helpful

Comment: If you are trying to answer your own question .. then it's fine, just do it properly: have a question here and answer it separately.

Comment: BTW, this particular issue has been fixed in the next major 2023.3 version -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-330531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the linked pages the ".lock" file would need to be removed from the application. In my instance is was removed from here.

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.2
```

Comment: This is windows version